# php prevent specific repeating rows

Tags: php, rows

I have a sample PHP code

```
  <?php 
   for ($x=0; $x<=3; $x++) {
    echo '<tr><td>Column $x</td>';
    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee` ");

    echo '<table border=1>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td>Nickname:".$row{'Nickname'}."</td><td>Hours: ".$row{'hours'}."</td>";
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';    
    echo '</tr>';
   } 
?>
```

and the result is something like this.

```
                Column 1                    Column 2                   Column 3   
Nickname: John  Hours: 1  |  Nickname: John Hours:  1 | Nickname: John Hours: 1
Nickname: Foo   Hours: 2  |  Nickname: Foo  Hours:  2 | Nickname: Foo  Hours: 2
```

I need to eliminate specific repeating rows. I dont need to repeat the Nickname Row.

the output should be like this
                    Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
    Nickname: John  Hours: 1  |  Hours:  1 |  Hours: 1
    Nickname: Foo   Hours: 2  |  Hours:  2 |  Hours: 2

Comment: it feels like the query is returning repeated data, could you post the result from the mentioned query?

Comment: What is the exact purpose of For loop here?

Comment: Check the answers, plenty of good ones there

Comment: I need the for loop the column

Comment: Check my answer with grouping and some more suggestions

Comment: the for loop serves on columns I dont need the group.

Comment: If you find an answer you're happy with, please tick it as accepted. If you don't, please update your question so we can help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you solve this easily in PHP.

```
<?php 
for ($x=0; $x<=3; $x++) {

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee` ORDER BY `Nickname`");

echo '<table border=1>';
$nick = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if($nick != $row{'Nickname'} {
       if($nick != "") { echo '</tr>'; }
       echo '<tr>';
       echo "<td>Nickname:".$row{'Nickname'}."</td>";
  }
  echo "<td>Hours: ".$row{'hours'}."</td>";
  $nick = $row{'Nickname'};
}
echo '</table>'; 
?>
```

In order for this to work as intended, you have to have all nicknames next to eachother, which you easily do with ORDER BY Nickname.

Comment: **GROUP BY** - better.

Comment: Good point, were just updating when you wrote. Didn't think about him not having ORDER BY in his query.

Comment: GROUP BY will only give him one hours-field. I'm not saying he has a good database structure from the beginning, but I'm giving him a answer he can use. If he would've given us a database structure I could help him better with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `For` loop part. Plus your code should be something like this:

```
<?php 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee`");

    echo '<table border=1>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td>Nickname:".$row{'Nickname'}."</td><td>Hours: ".$row{'hours'}."</td>";
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>'; 
  ?>
```

Try it out ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee` ");

    echo '<table border=1>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo "<td>Nickname:".$row['Nickname']."</td><td>Hours: ".$row['hours']."</td>";
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>'; 
  ?>
```

simply remove the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sql query

```
SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee`
```

to

```
SELECT max(id) as id, `Nickname`, sum(`hours`) as hours FROM `employee` GROUP BY `Nickname`
```

Also, pay attention that mysql_query (http://php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)  function is deprecated and you should use mysqli_query:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

i think order by and lastName variable can solve better

```
<?php 
for ($x=0; $x<=3; $x++) {

$result = mysql_query(" SELECT id, `Nickname`,`hours` FROM `employee` order by Nickname");

echo '<table border=1>';
$lastName='';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  if($row['Nickname']==$lastName)
  {
      echo "<td></td>";
  }
  else
  {
      echo "<td>Nickname:".$row{'Nickname'}."</td>";
      $lastName=$row['Nickname'];
  }
  echo "<td>Hours: ".$row{'hours'}."</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; 
?>
```

Comment: If you use order, why not use group by?

Comment: Actually the for loop serves my column for each query